# How to download and save output file?

Tags: curl, coldfusion, download, wget

We need to download a bunch of excel files. We're going to be looping over a list of links, downloading and saving the file at the link, and then eventually importing these files into our DB. We need to run this every night, so we would need to schedule it somehow.

Our web application runs on ColdFusion.

What would be the best (quickest/most efficient/easiest) way to accomplish this? Should we write a ColdFusion file (and then create a cf scheduled task to run it overnight) or can we run this using cURL or Wget? Or some sort of script (Perl/Python)?

Edit:

There will be up to 200 links or so (sometimes significantly less). We are using SQL Server 2008 (although that's not really applicable as I'm only asking about downloading the files to the folder - the importing will be a separate step handled within the db). And the files are binary excel files.

Comment: (Edit) As written your question is a little broad. What is your *specific* concern here? There is no single tool or "right" answer. It could be done with either CF or shell scripting + o/s scheduling tools. Sounds like you already know what pieces are needed: something to schedule the job and something to coordinate the pieces of the job (loop and download individual files). Also, please update your question to include 1) how many links 2) your dbms type and 3) the type of files - binary Excel files or text files ie .csv, .txt?.

Comment: @Leigh - I guess what I'm asking is why I would choose one over the other? And I'll add the information to the question

Comment: For 200 files, I am not sure there would be a significant difference. Especially if it is only a daily task run during off hours. I frequently use CF for this kind of task, because it simplifies the process of performing disparate tasks (scheduling, downloading, importing). Granted I typically use a "batch" approach so it scales better. The convenience of CF probably does add a bit of overhead, versus doing this at the o/s level instead (cron, wget, shell scripting). But I am not really a linux guy, so I could not give you specifics.

Answer (score 3):

,Depending on which ColdFusion server you have, ColdFusion schedules are efficient and easy. Create CFM file, loop over the links, save each excel in secure directory, then trigger another function to read the excel file by using ColdFusion built in excel functions refer to this [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17cba-7f87.html).
You can easily setup schedule task in ColdFusion Admin for more info how to setup schedule task refer to this [link](http://www.cfexecute.com/post/using-coldfusion-scheduled-tasks/).
If the process will take long time execution consider extending the timeout or separate into multiple jobs.